# Be or have question

Tags: grammar, tense, future-perfect, future

If I want to write this statement in future perfect tense, will this statement be correct?

`We will have been dead by then.`

Or should it be

`We will be dead by then.`

In the second sentence we can't use 'have' as we cannot write 'we will have dead by then' because being dead is a sate, not an activity so what will be the correct sentence in future perfect tense?

Answer (score 2):

As you say, *being dead* is a condition, not something that happens to you. *We will be dead by then* expresses your meaning without any need for the future perfect. If you particularly want to use it, you would have to say *We will have died by then.* Alternatively, you could add a period of time, for example *We will have been dead for many years by then.*

Answer (score 2):

When an adjective is used with a perfect tense, it means that description applies to some point in the past, with the usual perfect sense of "a connection to the present. Often the connection is to contrast with the present and imply that "now the description doesn't apply"  (though this implication can be changed with expressions like "for some time")

> I have been hot and I have been cold on this journey, but now I'm fine.

So "#I have been dead" has a rather odd meaning: "I was dead at some point in the the past, but now I'm alive". Perhaps this is possible in a discussion of reincarnation.

Casting this into the future makes no difference "We will have been dead by then" literally means that at that point in the future we will have died and come back to life.

You almost certainly mean "We will be dead", or "We will have died"